# How to ensure only single copy of variable is created in the entire program when including header files

Tags: c, encapsulation

In a C program I want that specific variables be shared by all files. Get and Set methods will  be used to access their data. However, their value will never be directly accessed. I think I need to use extern to do this. The code below is just to get the concept across. Is this how it would be done:

Header file:

```
//shared.h

#ifndef SHARED_H_
#define SHARED_H_

extern int var1;
extern int var2;

void set_var1(int i);
int get_var1();
void set_var2(int i);
int get_var2();

#endif /*SHARED_H_*/
```

Source file:

```
//shared.c

#include shared.h

int var1=0;
int var2=0;

void set_var1(int i)
{
  var1 = i;
}

int get_var1()
{
  return var1;
}

void set_var2(int i)
{
  var2 = i;
}

void get_var2()
{
  return var2;
}
```

I now have the following questions about this:

1) Is there no way in C that I hide the var1 and var2?

2) I think that they must be declared extern so that only a single copy exists in the whole program regardless of how many times the .h file is shared. Is my understanding correct?

3) If I do not use extern in the .h file then, in the .c file, regardless of whether I declare the var1 and var2 as static or not, they will never have a single copy in the program.

4) I can include the above .h file in source files i.e .c files in different modules of the program (not their .h file) and they will all share the exact same var1 and var2 if the code is written as above, correct?

As you can see, I have become confused about the difference between extern in .h and only declaring and defining a variable in .c file, when sharing variables with multiple files.

Thanks.

Comment: When you have get and set functions then the variable must not be declared in a header file.  Easy peasy.

Comment: OK Hans, but how do I ensure that there will be only a single copy of var1 and var2 if I do not declare them extern? The real shared.h shall be included in three different source files in my program. I just want that a single copy of var1 and var2 exist in the program. That is all.

Comment: You might be missing the point, you never need *extern* on a variable that is not declared in a header file.  Nobody can see it.  Except for the one .c source file defines it, the same one that has the get and set function definitions.

Comment: ok, lets assume that the variables are not declared at all in the header file and only declared and defined in the source file above. Will this insure that regardless of how many times and where I include the header file, there will be the same copy of var1 and var2 being accessed by my program.

Comment: Yes.   It is much more fun for SO contributors when you show us how that went wrong.

Comment: OK, the reason for my confusion: When we use #include, the preprocessor just puts does a copy paste of the program code (don't know if its the .h being copy pasted or .c) in the place of #include. This implied that without using extern and declaring the variable to be global, I will end up with unique copy of var1 and var2 making them not be shared across the program, each time I #include "shared.h" in any .c file in my entire program.

Comment: @quantum231 - The compiler does *exactly* what you tell it - `#include "x.h"` includes `x.h` and nothing else. No magic! And if the header doesn't mention the variables, no one will know about them.

Comment: yes, I undestand that Bo, but when I do #include across multiple source files, why won't that end up creating "multiple independant copies of var1 and var2 included in each of those places"?

Comment: @quantum231 it looks like you are still wound-around-the-axel on this one. `var1` and `var2` will **not** be in a header -- so there is no chance of multiple separate inclusion. You will have your `set()` and `get()` prototypes in the header file, but`var1` and `var2` will be in the source file where `set()` and `get()` are defined and can operate on them. Since they are standard types, (`int`) no `typedef` or *forward declaration* is required.

Comment: `int var1=0; int var2=0;` is in `shared.c` . No idea why you think they would also be in other units.

Comment: I see, so it is only the .h which is copy posted and not the .c

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you can hide `var1` and `var2` by simply removing the `extern` declarations from the header file and changing the declarations in the source file to `static`. That will prevent the linker from exposing their definitions to other files.

2, 3 ,4) `extern` is not what ensures "a single copy exists in the program", that's the point of the guard macros in the header file though.

```
//shared.h

#ifndef SHARED_H_
#define SHARED_H_

/* uncomment these for public variables */
// extern int var1; 
// extern int var2;

void set_var1(int i);
int get_var1();
void set_var2(int i);
int get_var2();

#endif /* SHARED_H_ */
```

```
//shared.c

#include "shared.h"

/* also delete the `static` qualifier for public variables */
static int var1 = 0;
static int var2 = 0;

void set_var1(int i)
{
  var1 = i;
}

int get_var1()
{
  return var1;
}

void set_var2(int i)
{
  var2 = i;
}

void get_var2()
{
  return var2;
}
```

Comment: Why declare them in the header? I don't know if they should be declared in the header. All I know is that I want the variables to be shared i.e single copy in the whole program regardless of how many times the header is included in the program's multiple source files.

Answer (score -1):

Although, it is not standard, you may use `#pragma once`[1] as an alternative include guards. Many modern compilers do support it.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once